# Is the function star: $P(\Sigma^{*})\to P(\Sigma^{*}) $ by $star(L)=L^{*}$ surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, Define the function star: $P(\Sigma^{*})\to P(\Sigma^{*}) $ by $star(L)=L^{*}$
>
> > Is the function $star$ surjective?
> >
> > Is the function $star$ injective?

Here is what I think:

The domain and range of star is $P(\Sigma^{*})$.

For a function to be injective it must be that for all $L_1, L_2 \in P(\Sigma^{*}): star(L_1)=star(L_2) \implies L_1 =L_2$ however consider languages $\phi^{*}=\{\lambda\} $ and ${\lambda}^{*} = \{\lambda\}$, clearly both languages are different but provide the same output hence this function cannot be injective.

I am not quite sure for the surjective part: $\forall y \in P(\Sigma^{*}), \exists x \in P(\Sigma^{*}) $ such that $star(x)=y$. I am struggling to find a counter example for this which leads me to believe that this function is surjective however I am not quite sure.

Comment: If a language is in the image of star, then $L^* = L$. But there are some languages which do not satisfy this.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff what is the image?

Comment: Your $\phi^\ast$ and $\lambda^\ast$ look quite the same to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injectivity fails clearly as $\{a,b,ab\}$ and $\{a,b,ba\}$ have the same star, namely $\Sigma^\ast$.

No $L^\ast$ can be finite when $L$ is non-empty and contains a non-empty string. 
That's an easy way to show non-surjectiveness.